# Tool tip jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used the jTip Theme for tooltip from the site http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/. The toolip close when click the close icon. I need the tooltip to be close on pressing esc key too. How can i do that?

Comment: try qTip http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/ a very nice and supportive plugin

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the source of the PlugIn for that. Insert this after line 458 of the PlugIn:

```
$(window).bind("keydown.cluetip", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        cluetipClose();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you find one nice tooltip here

http://trentrichardson.com/downloads/

csstooltips.zip

Comment: It does n't have close button.